# Mapping over a graphql-api Handler

Tags: haskell, graphql, haskell-graphql

I’ve been trying to use [the Haskell `graphql-api` library](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/graphql-api), which uses some `servant`-style type trickery to represent a GraphQL API at the type level. It provides the [`Handler`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/graphql-api-0.1.2/docs/GraphQL-Resolver.html#t:Handler) type family, which is used to provide actual implementations of GraphQL APIs. I have created a simple API for testing purposes:

```
type Query = Object "Query" '[]
  '[ Argument "id" Text :> Field "test" (Maybe Foo) ]

type Foo = Object "Foo" '[]
  '[ Field "name" Text ]
```

I also have a Haskell type that represents the `Foo` resource, as well as a function for retrieving it from the database:

```
data ServerFoo = ServerFoo
  { name :: Text
  } deriving (Eq, Show)

lookupFoo :: Text -> IO (Maybe ServerFoo)
```

Now, I want to implement a `Handler` for `Query`. To start, I implemented a `Handler` for `Foo`:

```
viewFoo :: ServerFoo -> Handler IO Foo
viewFoo ServerFoo { name } = pure $ pure name
```

Then I went to implement the root handler, but I realized I am not sure how to use my `viewFoo` function when I end up with with a `Maybe ServerFoo`. I tried this:

```
handler :: Handler IO Query
handler = pure $ \fooId -> do
  foo <- lookupFoo fooId
  sequence $ fmap viewFoo foo
```

However, this does not work. It produces the following type error:

```
• Couldn't match type ‘IO Text’
                 with ‘Object "Foo" '[] '[Field "name" Text]’
  Expected type: ServerFoo
                 -> IO (Object "Foo" '[] '[Field "name" Text])
    Actual type: ServerFoo -> Handler IO Foo
• In the first argument of ‘fmap’, namely ‘viewFoo’
  In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘fmap viewFoo foo’
  In a stmt of a 'do' block: (sequence $ fmap viewFoo foo)
```

This seems a bit odd to me, given that the examples I’ve read would seem to imply that `Handler`s are designed to be compositional. Indeed, they appear to be, since making a few tweaks to remove the `Maybe` makes this typecheck:

```
type Query = Object "Query" '[]
  '[ Argument "id" Text :> Field "test" Foo ]

handler :: Handler IO Query
handler = pure $ \fooId -> do
  Just foo <- lookupFoo fooId
  viewFoo foo
```

Obviously, however, this involves a partial pattern match, so it’s not an okay solution.

My conclusion is that either `Handler IO` is not a functor or `Handler m (Maybe a)` is stranger than I’m anticipating. Whatever the reason, this seems like a fairly straightforward use case, so I would imagine there has to be some solution.

Comment: You should look at the actual definition of `Handler IO X` to see what types are not matching up. The type of `viewFoo` is `.. -> IO (IO Foo)`, so `sequence . fmap viewFoo` is `IO (Maybe (IO ..))` whereas `handler :: IO (IO ..)`. GHCs insistence in not expanding type families is only harmful here, so just remove them from your type annotations. Also, I'm not sure the latter program is relevant - your 'tweaks' are essentially just an entirely different term (because both terms are so small to begin with), so it is unrelated to the former program.

Comment: @user2407038 Yes, I did glean that—I actually ended up spending a fair amount of time inspecting the source definitions of `Handler`—but even after doing that, though it explained why what I tried wasn’t working, I still wasn’t sure how to actually solve my problem.